# Particles passing through a surface

Tags: geometry, flow, volume

Today is the day I ask silly questions :

[image]

The book says the particles passing through the surface $dS$ are the ones contained in the cylinder of volume $dS.v.dt.cos(\theta)$ but I really don't see why.

For me, all the particles in the volume $dS.v.dt$ (which is bigger than $dS.v.dt.cos(\theta)$) will pass through the surface. I don't understand the need of putting $cos(\theta)$ in the equation...

Comment: what does $\vec{u}$ mean? It seems like the velocity is changing?

Comment: $\vec{u}$ is just the unit vector normal to $dS$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at large $\theta$ : fewer particles per unit time will reach the surface because their perpendicular velocity is much less. When $\theta = \pi/2 $ zero particles cross the surface.

Answer (score 2):

The volume of the shape drawn there *is*  $dS\,v\,dt\cos(\theta)$.
$dS$ is not a cross section, it is at an angle to the axis $v$ is aligned with.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply multiply $dS$ with $\vec{v}$ to obtain the volume.
If we assume a coordinate system $x$ perpendicular to $dS$, and $y$ in the plane of $dS$.

The volume is defined as:
$$V=\int^{s_{begin}}_{s_{end}} \: S \vec{dx}_{\perp S}$$
However, if we want to express it as a function of $v dt$ we get:

$$V=\int^{t_{begin}}_{t_{end}}  \: S \: \vec{(v dt)}_{\perp S} \: =\int^{t_{begin}}_{t_{end}}  \: S \: \vec{v}_{\perp S} \: dt $$

This shows $\vec{v}_{\perp S}$ which is in this case $\vec{v} \: cos(\theta)$ which is equal to $\vec{u}$

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, with larger $\theta$ (as long as it's not $\pi/2$) it is still cylinder of volume $dS.v.dt$ that will pass through the surface $dS$

[image]

Comment: But what is the **size** of $dS$ as $\theta$ gets large? I believe the original question is to find the flux per unit area, not per $dS$ .

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand...
Those two cylinders have the same volume $S.L$:

[image]

So all particles exactly on (or beyond) surface $S$ at point $A$ and time $t$ will be exactly on (or beyond) surface $S$ shifted at point $B$ by time $(t+dt)$ assuming they all move at constant velocity $\vec{v}$.
I don't see how the orientation of the surface changes anything.

I can't believe I'm stuck on something like this...